# How to get specific column number based on text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have table which has columns like below

```
<tr>
    <th class="column1">...</th>
    <th class="column2">...</th>
    <th class="column3">...</th>
    <th class="column4">...</th>
</tr>
```

I can get particular element like `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/th[@class="column3"]')`

How can I get which is the column number? i.e. for column3 `num=3`.
So that I can use `num` to select specific text for other rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly,

```
count(//tr/th[@class="column3"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1
```

gets the sequential number of the element you select

Comment: In python count works like if a is list `a = [1,2,3,1]`  as `a.count(1)`. The above doesn't work, do you mean to say `count(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/th[@class="clicks"]/preceding-sibling::th'))` . I tried this but gives error count is not defined

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('count(//tr/th[@class="column3"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1')`

Comment: it's tries to find path with count in it since you put in inverted commas. I tried putting it outside inverted comma but then it gives count not defined error

Comment: it know nothing about selenium, but look there http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=0c3a5552-9169-4b87-a6b9-36a9afd929f9-xpath

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number in your column like **column1** then you can extract it first using .getText method and then use split function to separate the string with number

Refer :-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a collection of elements that are all columns and then you can try catch if a column will have a specific attribute. then the index element would be your column. Hope it helps.